# Differentiator step response

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, control, gain, step-response

I have one ideal and one practical differentitiator circuit in Multisim to which I am applying a positive, say 10 V step response. The output I get has a much lower settling time at final value of 0 for practical differentiator whereas the ideal differentiator oscillates which makes perfect sense for me. However, this output (see shape below) seems to start from a random big negative value for both which I do not understand as I expected it to be a positive big value as even under ideal step input the Dirac delta function goes to positive infinity and for s simulated step input the gradient is still likely to be very high rather than low.Both my differentiators are in inverted configuration but I do not think this should affect expected output. Can anyone please point me to a resource where I can study why do I get a negative initial value from my differentiator for a positive step input.
I think it is saturating to the negative rail, why the negative rail and not positive.
[image]

Comment: (a) The graph you have is not from a differentiator , it looks more like the system response of a closed loop control system.

Comment: b) a differentiator made with a single op-amp would have an inverting response, however you would test this with a ramp input signal, e.g. start at 1v then ramp up to 2v over 1 second then stay at 2v , the output would be a negative 1v pulse lasting for 1 second , (assuming your differentiator has a 1 second time constant.

(c) driving a step signal into an opamp differentiator will just cause it to saturate at one of the rails for a long time, then decay back to zero.

Comment: @BobT How do I know which rail will it saturate to.

Comment: An op amp differentiator is (usually) inverting , so if you put a positive edge in , it will saturate to the negative rail.   When it saturates , the "virtual earth" condition at the op-amp input is lost, and takes a while to recover from this. In a real world differentiator used in a control system, there would be strategically placed diodes to make the overload recovery much faster and more predictable.

Comment: Like all op-amp circuits utilising a :"virtual earth"  the transfer function will always be inverting. If you imagine the op-amp as a see-saw then the virtual earth is the pivot in the middle, there is some component attached from user input to the virtual earth , i.e. the left side off the see-saw , and some component in the feedback path (the right side of the see saw)  so if you pull up on the left side, the right side must go down to keep it balanced.